# Actionscript 3 resetting a game?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a memory game here and when the game ends or the timer runs out, the user is brought to a game over page, containing a reset button.

My problem is when I hit the reset button, it brings me back to the main game page, it does all sorts of weird things.

Also, when I get to the game over page, I'm getting errors with my timer.

Here is my code:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.text.TextField;

public class MemoryGame extends MovieClip{

private var firstTile:cards;
private var secondTile:cards;
private var pauseTimer:Timer;
private var score:int;
private var cardCount:int;
var seconds:Number;
var minutes:Number;


var numberDeck:Array = new Array(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6);


public function MemoryGame(){

    //TIMER FUNCTION
    var levelTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 180);
    levelTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);
    levelTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);

    // LEVEL FUNCTION
    easyBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, easyButtonClicked);
    medBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, medButtonClicked);
    hardBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, hardButtonClicked);

    score = 0;
    txtScore.text=""+score;

    //Level button events
    function easyButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
        removeChild(levelText);
        trace("easy button clicked!");
        seconds = 0;
        minutes = 1;
        txtTime.text = "1:00";
        levelTimer.start();
        setupTiles();
    }

    function medButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
        removeChild(levelText);
        trace("medium button clicked!");
        seconds = 30;
        minutes = 0;
        txtTime.text = "0:30";
        levelTimer.start();
        setupTiles();
    }

    function hardButtonClicked(e:MouseEvent):void{
        removeChild(levelText);
        trace("hard button clicked!");
        seconds = 15;
        minutes = 0;
        txtTime.text = "0:15";
        levelTimer.start();
        setupTiles();
    }


    //Timer handlers
    function timerHandler(e:TimerEvent):void {
        if (seconds > 00) {
        seconds -=1;
        }

        else {
            if (minutes > 0) {minutes -=1;seconds = 59;}
    }
            txtTime.text = minutes+":"+(seconds >= 10 ? seconds : "0"+seconds);
        }

    function timerCompleteHandler(e:TimerEvent):void {
        e.target.reset();
        e.target.stop();

    }



    //Tiles set up
    function setupTiles(){
    for(x=1; x<=4; x++) {
        for (y=1; y<=3; y++){
            var randomCard = Math.floor(Math.random()*numberDeck.length);
            var tile:cards = new cards();
            tile.card = numberDeck[randomCard];
            numberDeck.splice(randomCard,1);
            tile.gotoAndStop(9);
            tile.x = (x-0.5) * 150;
            tile.y = (y-0.5) * 200;
            tile.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,tileClicked);
            addChild(tile);
            cardCount = cardCount + 1
        }
    }
}


}




public function tileClicked(event:MouseEvent) {
    var clicked:cards = (event.currentTarget as cards);
    if (firstTile == null){
        firstTile = clicked;
        firstTile.gotoAndStop(clicked.card);
    }

    else if (secondTile == null && firstTile != clicked){
        secondTile = clicked;
        secondTile.gotoAndStop(clicked.card);
        if (firstTile.card == secondTile.card){
            pauseTimer = new Timer(1000, 1);
            pauseTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,removeCards);
            pauseTimer.start();

        }
        else {
            pauseTimer = new Timer(1000, 1);
            pauseTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,resetCards);
            pauseTimer.start();
        }
    }

    if (seconds == 0){
        pauseTimer.stop();
        this.gotoAndStop(3);


    }
}


public function resetCards(event:TimerEvent) {
    firstTile.gotoAndStop(9);
    secondTile.gotoAndStop(9);
    firstTile = null;
    secondTile = null;
    pauseTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,resetCards);
    score = score - 2;
    txtScore.text=""+score;
}


public function removeCards(event:TimerEvent){
    removeChild(firstTile);
    removeChild(secondTile);
    firstTile = null;
    secondTile = null;
    pauseTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,removeCards);
    score = score + 10;
    txtScore.text=""+score;
    cardCount = cardCount - 2;
    trace("Cardcount: " + cardCount);

    if (cardCount == 0){


        this.gotoAndStop(2);
        txtFinalScore.text=" "+score;
        pauseTimer.stop();          
        }
            }
}   
}
```

And here is my code for the reset button:

```
button_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, resetGame);

function resetGame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
score = 0;
seconds = 0;
pauseTimer.stop();

this.gotoAndStop(1);

}
```

Comment: What are the weird things and what is the error you're getting? Try to be a bit more specific. (Maybe add some screenshots?)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you remove all your event listeners in your reset method BEFORE this.gotoAndStop();

```
button_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, resetGame);

function resetGame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
score = 0;
seconds = 0;
pauseTimer.stop();

levelTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerCompleteHandler);
levelTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerHandler);

this.gotoAndStop(1);

}
```

This is only an example. You should remove all the event listeners you can, because this.gotoAndStop(1); will only add more listeners, without removing the ones from the previous frame. This is why everything goes haywire.

Comment: I tried to do it your way Captain-Rayne Martin, I'm trying to stop the levelTimer but it comes up with error "Access of undefined property levelTimer", "Access of undefined property TimerCompleteHandler" and "Access of undefined property timerHandler"

Comment: Also, how can I go about resetting the entire game?